# Fancybox - Photo in portrait format shivers with Thumbnail Helpers

Tags: fancybox

I'm using the latest version of fancybox on my private web-page. When displaying upright fotos that are higher than the resolution of the screen the foto shivers (only in upright format, not horizontal).

Example on http://www.jorek-bremen.de/foto_spielereien.html. Click on the picture under "Ultraweitwinkel-Aufnahmen" to open the gallery. The first picture is horizontal and stands still, even if you reduce the size of the browser-window. The second foto is in portrait (1024px high) and shivers up and down in high frequency irrespective of the size of the browser-window.

This phenomenon does not appear by using the button helper as you can see by clicking on the foto under "Allgemeine Spielereien".